ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. No irregular datatype or jagged array not a duplicate
Ok, I found this weird.
I am building a text classifier. I have used the gensim's word2vec with aggregation when I try to run it through an sklearn classifier it gives me the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Here is my KNN code
def knn(X_train, y_train, k):
    start = time.time()
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    X_train, y_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True), y_train.reset_index(drop=True)  
    check_inconsistencies(values=X_train)
    check_inconsistencies(values=y_train)
    #  X_train, y_train = np.asarray(X_train, dtype=np.dtype), np.asarray(y_train, dtype=np.dtype)  
    print(f"KNN")
    knn.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
    net_time = time.time()-start
    return knn, net_time

where the check_inconsistencies is written by chatgpt to check if the data type or lenght is inconsistent
def check_inconsistencies(values):
    # Check if it's a sequence (like a list of lists)
    if isinstance(values, (list, tuple)):
        # 1. Check for inconsistent types
        types = set(type(v) for v in values)
        if len(types) > 1:
            print(f"Inconsistent types detected: {types}")
        else:
            print(f"Consistent type: {list(types)[0]}")
        
        # 2. Check if all elements are also sequences (to verify shapes)
        if all(isinstance(v, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)) for v in values):
            # Check for shape inconsistencies
            lengths = [len(v) for v in values]
            if len(set(lengths)) > 1:
                print(f"Inconsistent lengths detected: {lengths}")
            else:
                print(f"Consistent shape: All sub-lists/arrays have length {lengths[0]}")
        else:
            print("Not all elements are sequences; some may be single values.")
    
    # If the input is a NumPy array, check its dtype consistency
    if isinstance(values, np.ndarray):
        print(f"NumPy array detected with dtype: {values.dtype}")
        print(f"Shape: {values.shape}")
    
    # Try to convert to NumPy array and catch potential errors
    try:
        arr = np.asarray(values)
        print("Array created successfully:", arr)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error encountered: {e}")

Additionally I also wrote by myself the following check of consistency for the code
    for x in vec_pooled:
        count1 += 1
        if (type(x) != type(prev1)) or (len(x) != len(prev1)):
            print(f"\nMismatch1:   {type(x)} not {type(prev1)}           {len(x)} not {len(prev1)}           {count1}")
            print(f" {x} \n {prev1}  \n\n\n\n")
            prev1 = x
        for y in x:
            count2 += 1
            if (type(y) != type(prev2)) or (len(y) != len(prev2)):
                print(f"\nMismatch2:   {type(y)} not {type(prev2)}           {len(y)} not {len(prev2)}           {count2}")
                print(f" {x} \n {prev1}  \n\n\n\n")
                prev2 = y
            for z in y:
                count3 += 1
                if type(z) != type(prev3):
                    print(f"Mismatch3:{type(z)} not {type(prev3)}           {count3}")
                    prev3 = z
            count3 = 0
        count2 = 0
        print("Loop Completed")
        print (f"Type of prev1: {type(prev1)}")
        print (f"Type of prev2: {type(prev2)}")
        print (f"Type of prev3: {type(prev3)}")
    return vec_pooled

Both run fine ,so I know that the array isn't jagged or of inconsistent types. But on running the code normally the following issue occours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
      1 bakara = [3, ["./bakara.xlsx"], "text", "label"]
----> 2 df = pd.DataFrame(master_function(bakara))

Cell In[25], line 40
     38 temp_df['vec_text'] = vectorization(temp_df["prep_text"], vec ,agg_type, avg, None)
     39 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(temp_df['vec_text'], df[data[3]], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
---> 40 train_result = model_training_master(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
     41 print(f"{Agg_type}   |   {avg}  |   {vec}")
     42 for result in train_results:

Cell In[24], line 4
      1 def model_training_master(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
      2     training_result = []
----> 4     model, time = knn(X_train, y_train, max(y_train))
      5     accuracy, recall, f1 = model_performance(model, y_train, y_test)
      6     training_result.append("KNN", False, 0, time, accuracy, recall, f1)
...
-> 1022 arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   1023 if using_copy_on_write() and astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype):
   1024     arr = arr.view()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Meanwhile if I uncomment the KNN line the following error occours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 2
      1 bakara = [3, ["./bakara.xlsx"], "text", "label"]
----> 2 df = pd.DataFrame(master_function(bakara))

Cell In[25], line 40
     38 temp_df['vec_text'] = vectorization(temp_df["prep_text"], vec ,agg_type, avg, None)
     39 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(temp_df['vec_text'], df[data[3]], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
---> 40 train_result = model_training_master(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
     41 print(f"{Agg_type}   |   {avg}  |   {vec}")
     42 for result in train_results:

Cell In[24], line 4
      1 def model_training_master(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
      2     training_result = []
----> 4     model, time = knn(X_train, y_train, max(y_train))
      5     accuracy, recall, f1 = model_performance(model, y_train, y_test)
      6     training_result.append("KNN", False, 0, time, accuracy, recall, f1)

Cell In[29], line 7
      5 check_inconsistencies(values=X_train)
      6 check_inconsistencies(values=y_train)
----> 7 X_train, y_train = np.asarray(X_train, dtype=np.dtype), np.asarray(y_train, dtype=np.dtype)  
      8 print(f"KNN")
      9 knn.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)

TypeError: Cannot convert np.dtype into a dtype.

So the same code inside KNN causes a different error that one outside

Using dtype=np.dtype is just plain wrong.  np.dtype is a function that makes a dtype instance, not an instance itself.

The ... before line 1022 may be hiding valueable information.  Without careful study I wouldn't trust the chat answer.

What happens with np.array(X_train, dtype=float)?  with y_train?

dtype=dtype is not the same as dtype=np.dtype
